# Performing calculations on attributes between entities in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to xcode/ios etc... and having a little trouble figuring out a problem. I cant seem to figure out how I would retrieve and perform calculations on attributes between entities in core data. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

My project is a football app that has a one to many relationship. Season to Game (Season has a bunch of games. Season has attributes like teamname and datestart. Game has attributes like passing yards, running yards etc..

How would I be able to calculate something like total passing yards for the whole season (adding all the games passing yards together for that season)?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You managed object for **Season** has a relationship named **hasGames** (or whatever you named the relationship to the games). When you have a Season managed object, you can just access the **hasGames** relationship (it's an **NSSet**), loop through all the games in there and do whatever you want with the data, e.g. adding some values up.

**EDIT**:

Example:

If I take your Relationships Career -> Season -> Game, and suppose the relationships are called Career.hasSeasons and Season.hasGames, it would look something like this

```
int passingYards = 0;

Career* myCareer = [... fetchedresult for the career you are looking for ...];

for(Season* season in myCareer.hasSeasons)
{
  for(Game* game in season.hasGames)
  {
    careerPassingYards += [game.passingYards intValue];
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a code example of your suggestion above I would be very greatful. also would this be better than the method I posted below? like I said I am pretty new to this stuff thanks again.

Comment: This works thank you so much!!!!!! I was attempting to make a predicate with sub queries that would somewhat perform this looping process since I will be repeating this process for passing,rushing,tackles, etc... which would be the better way? Dont get me wrong I am super thankful I just want to make sure I am doing stuff right since I am very new to pretty much everything xcode/objective C. thanks again!!

Comment: Honestly, I don't know - at least for smaller datasets either way should be ok, probably for large datasets a query-only approach is more performant, I didn't test that yet as I only have relatively small databases up to now. And I like the descriptive power of just accessing the relationships like I described - I think that's a great feature of managed objects.

Comment: Thanks again as a test I am going to do one view like you suggested and one view like below and see how performance is. On my mac they look the same so I am thinking you are right about it not really mattering with small sets like we are working with. Anyways thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding this code here on stack.
After properly setting up my fetchedResultsController I am able to use this code in a button or where ever needed to calculate the total passing yards for all of the games in my season.

```
int totalpassingyards = 0;
for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
    NSNumber *objectTotalPassingYardsNumber = [object valueForKey:@"passingyards"];
    int objectTotalPassingYards = [objectTotalPassingYardsNumber intValue];      
    totalpassingyards = totalpassingyards + objectTotalPassingYards;
}
NSLog(@"Subtotal: %i", totalpassingyards);
```

My next step is to figure out how to calculate the total passing yards for all of the seasons in my career list. Here is how my coredata relationships are set up.

```
Career          >       Season      >       Game
(career stats)          (season stats)      (game stats)

career stats = sum of season stats
season stats = sum of game stats
game stats = that individual games stats
```

I am guessing this will consist of creating two fetchedResultsControllers one holding the games and one for holding the seasons and then doing some type of nested loop to get through all them. I will keep everyone updated.

If anyone has a better way to do this let me know like I said I am very new to this so everything really comes down to trail and error and although it might work I understand it might not be the best way to do it lol.